# LINQ inner join condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Suppose I have the following tables:

```
**Members**
Code  Name
001   Sue
002   Peter
003   John

**Sales Info**
MemCode   Date        Type (A/B)  Values
001       17/12/2013  A           100
001       17/11/2013  B           100
002       16/12/2013  A           100
```

I want to have the following result table

```
**Member Sales in 2013**
MemCode  Jan(A) Jan(B) Feb(A) ... Nov(B) Dec(A) Dec(B)
001       0      0      0          100    100    0
002       0      0      0          0      100    0
```

I tried to exact some data (The Nov(A) and Nov(B)) first using the query,

```
var query = from tb in Members
            join tb2 in SalesInfo on tb.MemCode equals tb2.MemCode
            join tb3 in SalesInfo on tb.MemCode equals tb3.MemCode
            where tb2.Type.Equals("A") &&
                  tb2.Date.Month.Equals(11)
                  tb3.Type.Equals("B") &&
                  tb3.Date.Month.Equals(11)
            Select ...
```

However it returns no data as no A record found in November so the whole row is filtered. Is there any suggestion to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if you want type A and type B, you should select on type == A OR type == B. No row will ever satisfy both conditions :)

Something like this is simpler and probably more effective

```
var query = from tb in Members
            join tb2 in SalesInfo on tb.MemCode equals tb2.MemCode
            where (tb2.Type.Equals("A") ||
                   tb2.Type.Equals("B")) &&
                   tb2.Date.Month.Equals(11)
            Select ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are asking for (Type==A && Type==B) and it is impossible. You can select A first, and get B value of same date in a subquery.